# Sharepoint survey - Condition to multiple responses

Tags: sharepoint, conditional-statements, survey, restriction

I have a sharepoint survey in which the first question is of type choice, where you have to chose a person. The survey allows multiple responses, and I was wondering if I could put a condition or restriction to that first question, so each person who responds can select a person from the list only in one response.

For instance I have as choice for the question "a" and "b". In my first response I choose "a", which will mean that if I want to respond again, I can only choose "b".

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "cascading". You want cascading lookup/dropdown fields.

Problem is: Doesn't work out of the box. You will have to create your own survey page or use a Javascript solution.

You didn't state your Sharepoint version, but there is a company called KWiz and they offer a custom Sharepoint 2007 Survey webpart which offers what you would need I think: [Survey Web Part - Survey Plus](http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-survey-web-part/overview/) - besides that I can only think of custom solutions.

---

**EDIT**

Seems like I misunderstood. Different use case:

- Your Survey allows multiple answers
- Your respondent responds to the survey with A
- Second time around the respondent may only choose B, or C - A is not available anymore

This would either be possible with Javascript, by querying the list what the previous responses of the user were and based on that grey out / disable these. But I think it would be easier to do a custom Survey entry form for this. You just have to inherit from the default survey list template and create a custom survey list template - in that you can do what you want then.

Comment: I don't think this is what Mimi is asking. I think the requirement is that once a user selects choice ABC... the next time the same user opens the survey choice ABC is not available. But I think your solution would be the same: probably some JavaScript on the form.

Comment: I probably misunderstood then... Maybe Mimi can enlighten us ;-)